# Ruby - How is MatchData object created without .new?

Tags: ruby, class, instantiation

I'm creating a class (say, `Bar`) for an object to be returned by a method of another class (say, `Foo#bar`), pretty much [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/MatchData.html) object is returned by [`Regexp#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match).

But the class `MatchData` does not have `.new`!

I know I don't need to imitate `MatchData` implementation, but I'd like to understand it and know how to do it when I find it interesting. Suppose I don't want clients creating `Bar` objects unless by calling `Foo#bar`.

Questions:

1. Internally, how is `MatchData` object created without `.new`?
2. How can I implement it (imitating `MatchData` or not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MatchData.new` method is being [explicitly undefined](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_1/re.c#L3970-L3972):

```c
rb_cMatch  = rb_define_class("MatchData", rb_cObject);
rb_define_alloc_func(rb_cMatch, match_alloc);
rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cMatch), "new");    // <- here
```

You can do the same in pure Ruby via [`undef_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-undef_method):

```
class Bar
  class << self
    undef_method :new
  end

  def initialize
    @bar = '123'  # <- for demonstration purposes
  end
end
```

Trying to call `Bar.new` will now result in an error:

```
Bar.new #=> undefined method `new' for Bar:Class (NoMethodError)
```

To create a new instance without a `new` method, you can call [`allocate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Class.html#method-i-allocate) manually (and maybe `initialize`, too):

```
bar = Bar.allocate     #=> #<Bar:0x007f9eba047cd8>
Bar.send(:initialize)  #=> "123"
bar                    #=> #<Bar:0x007fd8e0847658 @bar="123">
```

(`send` is needed because `initialize` is private)

Comment: A lot of core classes break the rules for various reasons. Sometimes it's quite distressing that they've gone out of their way to be special.

Comment: You know, objects that can't be initialized, they're basically magical byproducts of other processes. Like Fixnum, it's not something you can call `Fixnum.new` on because integers are really only barely objects in the first place, internally speaking.

Comment: @tadman Ruby sacrifices purity for performance, and gets away with it.

Comment: Yep! Not disagreeing. Just saying the deeper you dig, the *stranger* things get.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with that you shouldn't. It's arubyic to go out of your way to constraint users to do what they want to do even if it's not public interface. A more idiomatic approach would be make it more explicit that it's not part of the public interface. You can do that by making the class private:

```
class RegexMockery
  class MatchDataMockery
    def initialize(whatever)
      puts "I'm being created #{whatever}"
    end

    def [](_)
      '42'
    end
  end
  private_constant :MatchDataMockery

  def match(string)
    MatchDataMockery.new(string)
  end
end

match_result = RegexMockery.new.match('foo')
  # I'm being created foo
  # => #<RegexMockery::MatchDataMockery:0x007fe990de2ed0>

match_result[0] # => '42'

RegexMockery::MatchDataMockery # !> NameError: private constant RegexMockery::MatchDataMockery referenced
```

But if you insist on people hating you, save the method, undef it and call it whenever you want to create instances:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(whatever)
    puts "Now you see me #{whatever}"
  end

  def brag
    puts "I can create Foos and you can't!!!1!!"
  end
end

class Bar
  foos_new = Foo.method(:new)
  Foo.singleton_class.send :undef_method, :new

  define_method(:sorcery) do
    foos_new.call('bar').brag
  end
end

Bar.new.sorcery
  # Now you see me bar
  # I can create Foos and you can't!!!1!!

Foo.new # !> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Foo:Class
```

Comment: I really hate `Integer`. And `Float`, it's the worst. Not to mention `Method` and `Encoding`. Oh, and the evil twins, `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` :-)

Comment: @Stefan, right, right? It's terrible. Give us `#new` or give us death! In all seriousness, there are just internal gimmicks there. For user created classes, no one should be doing this.

Comment: If it's okay for core classes, it should be allowed for user defined classes, too, shouldn't it? An anonymous or value-less `Integer` instance would be little strange.

Comment: @Stefan, The thinking wasn't *"lets break polymorphism just so they won't call `#new`"*. It was *"we can add `#new`, but lets not bloat things more for something no one will use"*. There are sensible defaults for all of these. `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` can be the respective existing instances. Number classes can take one argument and return it if it's that type of number and raise an error otherwise. Or possibly parse string representations of that number. `Encoding` can be the default encoding. `MatchData` can take a regex and a string and return the match result.

Comment: I actually wish they added `#new`s just for consistency's sake. Even excluding internal things, the core library is still not always idiomatic. If we have `Integer#succ` and `Integer#pred` does that mean it's a good idea to start shortening names like 80's C programmers.

Comment: `min`, `max`, `to_i`, `to_s`, `assoc`, `uniq`, `dup`, `ord`, `chr`, `tr`, ... the language is full of abbreviated method names.

Comment: Good point. I must make clear that my intention is not to annoy users or break things, but to understand how does Ruby implement uncommon behaviors which are not obvious, just to learn more.

Comment: @SonySantos, I see. Then the answer is - for `MatchData` it's just hardcoded in the Ruby interpreter. But if you meet it somewhere in the wild, the above is probably how it was implemented.

Comment: And I agree that Ruby could be more self-consistent. For example, I can't define singleton methods for `Integer` or `Symbol` objects, but I can do it for `true` and `nil` among others.